# Does a claim of "802.11n support" guarantee that the device works on 5 GHz?

Tags: wireless-networking

My home wireless network runs on 5 GHz due to a lot of interference on 2.4 GHz.

I am shopping for a wireless printer.  Obviously, I need one that works on 5 GHz, so I've been trying to find something advertised as "dual band." This has been hard to find -- not many devices are labeled as such.

Lacking this, is finding something labeled as "802.11n" enough?  Does that guarantee that it runs on 5 GHz in addition to 2.4 GHz?

Comment: No; 802.11n supports both 2.4Ghz and 5.0Ghz what frequency the device supports depends on the device.

Comment: 802.11AC is the 'minimal' standard that ensures dual band. I do wonder if a wired networked printer wouldn't be a better idea, its not like its going on walkabout any time soon...

Comment: A "wired network printer." Wired into what? The router itself?

Comment: I deleted my answer on this post since there seems to be some disagreement. I'm really quite sure that 802.11n devices _necessarily_ can function on either frequency band and [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009) agrees with me. Thoughts?

Comment: @misha256: That link and further research confirms that there are no 802.11n HP printers that work on 5GHz. I stand corrected.

Comment: Yup. Our printer has 802.11g *and* an ethernet connector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking for 802.11n is not enough, it does not guarantee that a device will operate at 5GHz.

A 802.11n device can support 2.4GHz only, 5GHz only, or both 2.4GHz and 5GHz.

Don't look for the term "dual-band" in a printer, that term is generally used in relation to routers. Rather, look at the specifications for 5GHz support.

Proof:

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Networking-and-Wireless/802-11n-support-2-4-or-5-GHz/td-p/588853

Answer (score 0):

No. 802.11n is capable of operating on both 2.4GHz and 5GHz, but that does not mean that an 802.11n device must support 5GHz.

802.11ac *only* operates on 5GHz. A device that supports AC will generally also be backwards compatible, but it will switch to N, G or B when on 2.4GHz.

If you find a device that supports 802.11ac, you can be certain that it can transmit on 5GHz

Comment: Are you certain? The actual IEEE standard specified that 802.11n works on either frequency band, so how could a device that ONLY works on 2.4GHz get away with calling itself 802.11n?

Comment: It's a bit unclear but indeed there is no requirement that an "n" device *must* support 5GHz. Cisco explains it well http://tinyurl.com/p45ywh2 (under heading **Single band vs. Dual band**).

Comment: I think it would be less confusing for everyone if we stick with the term 5GHz rather than 5.8GHz.

Comment: Still not sure I agree. The article distinguished between single and dual-band _routers_, but we already know OP has an dual-band router. It comments 'a simultaneous “n” device can operate in both frequencies at the same time.' but that is also not what we're talking about. The device only needs to be able to use 5GHz at any given time and any 802.11n device will support this.

Comment: @Catatonic27 I'm afraid that is not true. 5GHz support is not guaranteed. Real world example: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Networking-and-Wireless/802-11n-support-2-4-or-5-GHz/td-p/588853

Comment: You learn something new every day!

Comment: @misha256 You're right; I was thinking about the 5.8GHz band that is used in R/C transmitters.